# Android Webview NullPointerException

Tags: android, webview

What are possible error when I encountered the NullPointerException for Webview:

```
WebView webView;
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView3);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("...");
```

This is my webview3.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

NPE is on line `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

Comment: Where exactly do you get a null pointer exception?

Comment: at which line do you get NPE

Comment: on line `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

Answer (score 3):

May be missing to load the xml layout webview3.xml
ie. setContentView(R.layout.webview3.xml);

Answer (score 3):

Try this sample code,

**res/layout/webview3.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
           android:orientation="vertical" 
           android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 

      <WebView
              android:id="@+id/webview" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

set permission in **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And use this code in your `onCreate()` method.

```
setContentView(R.layout.webview3.xml);
WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mywebview.loadUrl("http://Enter your URL here");
WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
    View webViewLayout = ((LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
            .inflate(R.layout.web_main, null, false);
    WebView webView = (WebView) webViewLayout.findViewById(R.id.webview);
```