# NullPointerException in WebView on Android

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception, android-webview

What are possible error?
WebView don't open web page.

**This my code:**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
              @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                  page = tab0_list.get(position).bee_path;
                  /*String url = "http://tvapp.pcrevue.sk";
                  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                  i.setData(Uri.parse(url + stranka));
                  startActivity(i);*/ // it works but can not aproximate

                  WebView webView = (WebView) listView.findViewById(R.id.pageInfo);
                  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                  webView.loadUrl("http://tvapp.pcrevue.sk" + page);
            }
          });
```

my logcat:

```
03-25 09:01:20.262: E/AndroidRuntime(835): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 09:01:20.262: E/AndroidRuntime(835):  at sk.pcrevue.Tab0$1.onItemClick(Tab0.java:91)
```

**NullPointerException is on the line :** webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

this isn't good for me, don't working
[Android Webview NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476601/android-webview-nullpointerexception)

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the `webview` object is null or not. And use `view` instead of `listview` in

```
listView.findViewById(R.id.pageInfo);
```